# help with owncloud on ubuntu 17.10 1

Tags: networking, 17.10, owncloud-server

How to install Owncloud on Ubuntu 17.10 (Desktop or Server) and connect it to the outside of my home LAN in the easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please use Nextcloud because it is fully open source, more secure and has more features. 
First step is to install it on Ubuntu. This tutorial should work fine: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-nextcloud-on-ubuntu-16-04
You should setup https with letsencrypt to make sure the data is encrypted.
Then you have to configure your Router to forward port 443 to your ubuntu box. This depends on your router vendor how to do this.
Then you need some kind of dynamic DNS service to make sure that you can reach your server from